# What are the appraoches we can use to show "Google my business reviews" inside SharePoint modern page

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, spfx

We have an account with google where we have Google my business reviews. so can we embed these reviews inside SharePoint online?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the embed web part to display content from other sites in SharePoint Online:

[Add content to your page using the Embed web part](https://support.microsoft.com/office/add-content-to-your-page-using-the-embed-web-part-721f3b2f-437f-45ef-ac4e-df29dba74de8)

Comment: I read about google reviews and they does not provide a way to embed the reviews inside external web sites.. so not sure what are the options available for me?

Comment: Maybe build a web part and return them using Google's API? https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data

Comment: do you think it is achievable using SPFx ?

Comment: Yes, as long as you're allowed to call the API from other websites, I can't see any issues.